# Bolts-Swift Compiler Errors Swift 4

Tags: swift4, xcode9, bolts-framework, migrating

I've migrated to Swift 4 and I'm using pods.

Within my Bolts-Swift framework I'm getting expected type error.

```
public func continueWith<S>(_ executor: Executor = .default, continuation: @escaping ((Task) throws -> S)) -> Task<S> {
    return continueWithTask(executor) { task in
        let state = TaskState.fromClosure({
            try continuation(task)
        })
        return Task<S>(state: state as! TaskState<_>) // Error with this line
    }
```

[image: Swift 4 Compiler Errors]

It is expecting type Task "S" but it is returning that type?  Apologies if this is a broad question but I really have no clue here.

Answer (score 0):

The latest podspec only supports 3.0. If you want Swift 4 support you need to manually point to the repo

```
pod 'Bolts-Swift', :git => 'https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Swift.git'
```